# How can I change the color of the <select> Tag dependent on the option chosen (using pure JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I am trying to build a select tag, where dependent on the option chosen (colors in this case), I want the select tag box to change into that background-color. However, when I try this I can only get it to change to the uppermost child's color (black). How can make it, so it works as intended?

**What I have tried:** 
I have tried to find all children and put them into an array, however this seem not to work either.

I have inserted the HTML, CSS and JavaScript (Pure JS) I have so far:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('primaryColor');
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var children = parent.children; // [<div class="child..">]

select.onchange = function () {
    if (children[0]) {
      select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `];
    }
    else if (children[1]) {
      select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `];
    }
    else if (children[2]) {
      select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `];
    }
    else if (children[3]) {
      select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `];
    }
    else {
      select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
        background-color: purple;
        color: white;
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `];
    }
}
```

```css
/* <select> styles */
select {
    /* Reset */
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font: sans-serif;

    /* Personalize */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    /*border-radius: 10px;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

select option {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: gray;
}

select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

option:checked {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="parent" id="primaryColor">
  <option class="child" value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a color</option>
  <option class="child" value="0">Black</option>
  <option class="child" value="1">Red</option>
  <option class="child" value="2">Green</option>
  <option class="child" value="3">Blue</option>
  <option class="child" value="4">Purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: lease explain what is going on in the lines where you have `select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `.

Comment: It should overwrite/change the style of select tag, dependent on the current option selected. But might have understood it wrong (and can be made easier).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var select = document.getElementById('primaryColor')
select.onchange = () => {

  // Initial color
  let color = 'white'

  // Check background color and change font color accordingly
  if (select.value == '#fff') color = 'black'

  select.style.cssText = `
        background-color: ${select.value};
        color: ${color};
        border: 3px solid #333;
      `
}
```

```css
/* <select> styles */

select {
  /* Reset */
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font: sans-serif;
  /* Personalize */
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #aaaaaa;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

select option {
  color: white;
  background-color: gray;
}

select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

option:checked {
  background-color: #1abc9c;
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="parent" id="primaryColor">
  <option class="child" selected disabled hidden>
    Choose a color
  </option>
  <!-- Set value as the hex color -->
  <option class="child" value="#fff">White</option>
  <option class="child" value="#000">Black</option>
  <option class="child" value="#f00">Red</option>
  <option class="child" value="#0f0">Green</option>
  <option class="child" value="#00f">Blue</option>
  <option class="child" value="#204">Purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cool! But how can I make that code, such that I can give it a border (border: 3px solid #333;) and change the colors with hex values?

Comment: @Chrizzar I edited the code. Now each option element has a hex value that you can be set and the selected option style can also be adjusted using `select.style.cssText`  in the js code.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the quick answer btw. That is a much cleaner solution than what mine ever would have been and it works perfectly, as I wanted. Cleaver way to handle changing the color. Did not think of that (or knew I could do that). Now I know. Thanks! :D

Comment: Can you make such that, if the select.value is white, then the color of the text should be black, else it should be as shown above? @aerail301

Comment: @Chrizzar Can be done with a simple if condition. See updated answer.

Comment: Cool cool thanks! :D I really appreciate it :)
I tried something similar, but what you used and I missed was the let parameter and the color part after the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your if conditions are not written properly, you have only passed and existing value instead of a boolean expression which checks which color you have selected. In Javascript, passing a existing value is considered true, therefore it always ends up being black since it is the first check.

To fix this, inside every condition, for if the value selected by the select box is equal to the corresponding value of the color.

So if Black is selected, then this.value will be equal to zero, therefore you can turn the select box black if the (this.value) is equal to zero and vice versa.

but in my opinion, @aerial301's answer is much better and cleaner.

```js
var select = document.getElementById('primaryColor');
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var children = parent.children; // [<div class="child..">]

   select.onchange = function () {
  if (this.value === '0') {
  select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  `];
}
else if (this.value === '1') {
  select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  `];
}
else if (this.value === '2') {
  select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  `];
}
else if (this.value === '3') {
  select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  `];
}
else {
  select = this.options[this.style.cssText = `
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    border: 3px solid #333;
  `];
}
}
```

```css
/* <select> styles */
select {
    /* Reset */
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font: sans-serif;

    /* Personalize */
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 30px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    /*border-radius: 10px;*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

select option {
    color: inherit;
    background-color: gray;
}

select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

option:checked {
    background-color: #1abc9c;
}

select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="parent" id="primaryColor">
  <option class="child" value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a color</option>
  <option class="child" value="0">Black</option>
  <option class="child" value="1">Red</option>
  <option class="child" value="2">Green</option>
  <option class="child" value="3">Blue</option>
  <option class="child" value="4">Purple</option>
</select>
```

Comment: True that @aerial301 solution is cleaner :D, but learning how my solution could have been done, is also very educating for me :D So thank you. I gotta read up on the syntax of javascript, I see. So, thanks for the answer.